# How can I set the notes of a Hyper-v vm checkpoint using Microsoft Powershell?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Setting the notes of a vm checkpoint in Hyper-v can be achieved in the gui quite easily. These notes can then be retrieved using Powershell just as easily. However, I am unable to find a way to actually modify the notes of a vm checkpoint using Powershell.

The `Set-VM` cmdlet can modify the notes of a vm, but it does not accept the object type of `Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMSnapshot`, so that potential solution is eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to set snapshot notes using the Hyper-V cmdlets. The cmdlets are actually based on WMI/CIM and it turns out that we can modify snapshot notes using the [WMI/CIM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/windows-virtualization-portal).

As the API is non-intuitive to use, I have wrapped the code in a **reusable cmdlet**:

```sh
Function Set-VMSnapshotNotes {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $VmName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $SnapshotName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Notes
    )

    # Get VM
    $vm = Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2' -Query "Select * From Msvm_ComputerSystem Where ElementName='$VmName'"

    if( -not $vm ) {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError( [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new( 
            [Exception]::new("Could not find VM '$VmName'"), 'VmNameNotFound', [Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::ObjectNotFound, $VmName ))
        return
    }

    # Get VM snapshot settings
    $snapshot = $vm | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData -Association Msvm_SnapshotOfVirtualSystem |
        Where-Object ElementName -eq $SnapshotName

    if( -not $snapshot ) {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError( [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new( 
            [Exception]::new("Could not find snapshot '$SnapshotName' of VM '$VmName'"), 'SnapshotNameNotFound', [Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::ObjectNotFound, $SnapshotName ))
        return
    }       

    # This doesn't modify the live snapshot settings, but only the local configuration data!
    $snapshot.Notes = $Notes

    # To be able to actually modify the live snapshot, configuration must be serialized.
    $serializer = [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Serialization.CimSerializer]::Create()
    $snapshotBytes = $serializer.Serialize( $snapshot, [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Serialization.InstanceSerializationOptions]::None )
    $snapshotStr   = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString( $snapshotBytes )

    # Now we can use method ModifySystemSettings of CIM class Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService to actually modify the live snapshot settings.
    $service = Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root\virtualization\v2' -class 'Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService'
    $result = $service | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName ModifySystemSettings -Arguments @{ SystemSettings = $snapshotStr }

    # If ReturnValue is 4096, the operation is performed asynchronously and $result.Job contains a CIM_ConcreteJob instance.
    # I'm not sure if this needs to be handled in case of setting only snapshot notes.
    if( $result.ReturnValue -notin 0, 4096 ) {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError( [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new( 
            [Exception]::new("Failed to set VM notes for snapshot '$SnapshotName' of VM '$VmName'"), 'ModifySystemSettingsFailed', [Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::InvalidResult, $result.ReturnValue ))
        return
    }

    $result  # Output
}
```

**Usage example:**

```sh
$result = Set-VMSnapshotNotes -VmName 'TestVM' -SnapshotName 'Snapshot 1' -Notes "Foo Bar Baz $(Get-Date)"
"Result: $result"

$notes = Get-VMSnapshot -VMName 'TestVM' -Name 'Snapshot 1' | ForEach-Object Notes
"New notes: $notes"
```

**Output:**

```text
Result: @{Job=; ReturnValue=0; PSComputerName=}
New notes: Foo Bar Baz 12/24/2022 14:27:19
```

**Notes:**

- When `$result.ReturnValue` equals `4096`, the operation is done asynchronously. When testing with a local VM, it was always zero though. The asynchronous processing might occur when modifying a remote VM. Just keep in mind that the settings might not be changed immediately. Using the `$result.Job` instance one could possibly wait for the asynchronous operation to finish. For more information see [ModifySystemSettings](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/modifysystemsettings-msvm-virtualsystemmanagementservice).
- Using the same principle, other snapshot settings could be modified. See [Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/msvm-virtualsystemsettingdata) for the available properties that theoretically could be modified through the `$snapshot` variable in the code sample. Though in the GUI most settings are disabled, so this propably won't work programmatically as well.